# radio button question, based on its answer (yes or No) generate next question or ask set of details to fill in

Tags: c#, html, jquery, .net, vb.net

I am a newbie here. My task was to first show only one question(radio button with yes or no) in the page and if they answer YES, then dynamically another set of questions should be popped up, if they answer NO to the first question, another radio button question has to be popped up dynamically with in same page. and based on answer to that question, next set of text boxes should be asked to fill in.

I have a valid NY ID card

```
<%--other state ID--%>

    <tr id="OtherStateQuestion" runat="server" align="left" valign="middle" class="evenRow" >
        
        <td class="col2">I have a valid ID Card in another State:<br />
        </td>
        <td class="col3">               
            <asp:RadioButton TabIndex="1" runat="server" ID="rdoOtherStateCheckYes" Text="Yes" GroupName="OtherStateQstn" onclick="return DisableOtherStateQ();" /><span class="spacer0">&nbsp;</span>
            <asp:RadioButton TabIndex="2" runat="server" ID="rdoOtherStateCheckNo" Text="No" GroupName="OtherStateQstn" onclick="return DisableOtherStateQ();" /><span class="spacer0">&nbsp;</span>
            <asp:CustomValidator  runat="server" ID="CustomValidator1" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="vgOtherStateCheck" ClientValidationFunction="OtherStateCheck" ></asp:CustomValidator>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

```
    //DISABLE OTHER STATE LIcENCE/ID QUESTION 
    function DisableOtherStateQuestion() {
        document.getElementById("<%= OtherStateQuestion.ClientID %>").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("<%= rdoOtherStateCheckYes.ClientID %>").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("<%= rdoOtherStateCheckNo.ClientID %>").style.display = 'none';
        
    }

    function EnableOtherStateQuestion() {
        document.getElementById("<%= OtherStateQuestion.ClientID %>").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("<%= rdoOtherStateCheckYes.ClientID %>").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("<%= rdoOtherStateCheckNo.ClientID %>").style.display = 'block';
    }
```

and I have next other radio button questions and text boxes written for next Conditions.

My problem is all questions are getting displayed once the page is loaded.

First when the page is loaded I want to display only first question, and based on its answer I want to display next question.

Is it correct way to hide and show the radio buttons, and what should be done on server side in aspx.vb page...

Thanks in advance

Comment: *`first show only one radio button question in the page and if they answer YES`* If there is just one option, how can they answer any other way?

Comment: I mean One question to be displayed first, and based on YES or NO button click, then next question should be displayed